# Reproduce linear discriminant analysis projection plot

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, discriminant-analysis

I'm struggling with projection points in linear discriminant analysis (LDA). Many books on multivariate statistical methods illustrate the idea of the LDA with the figure below.

[image: figure-1]

The problem description is as follows. First we need to draw decision boundary, add perpendicular line and than plot projections of data points on it. I wonder how to add projection points to the perpendicular line.

Any suggestions / pointers?

Comment: Although in 2-class case it is feasible to draw decision boudary first and the discriminant axis second, the actual logic of LDA is opposite. You first have to draw the discriminant line(s). [See a question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/12861/3277) (+ important links in comments therein) how to draw discriminants. And about boundaries: [1](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/15983/3277), [2](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/92157/3277).

Comment: @ttnphns Your answers are really awesome, but still do not know where to start. If I understand correctly I need to extract eigenvector from `lda` object; this eigenvector multiplied by discriminant scores is then the discriminant axis?

Comment: Andrej. Extract the eigenvectors. We know that values of the discriminants (discriminant scores) are dependent on them. The key point is now is that since you want to show discriminant scores _in the space of_ the (centered) original variables, you have to conceptualize discriminants as the original variables _rotated in that space_ (exactly as we conceptualize principal components). Rotation is the multiplication of the original centered data by a [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix)...

Comment: (Cont.) Matrix which columns are the eigenvectors can be seen as a rotation matrix _if_ the sum of squares of each its column (i.e. each eigenvector) is unit-normalized. So normalize the eigenvectors and compute component scores as centered data multiplied by these eigenvectors.

Comment: (Cont.) What is left is to show the discriminants' axes as straight lines tiled by points which represent the discriminant scores. So, to plot the tiled line, we have to find the coordinates of each tiling point onto the original axes (the variables). The coordinates are easy to compute: each coordinate is the cathetus, the discriminant score is the hypotenuze, and the cos of the angle between them is the corresponding element of the eigenvector matrix: cathet=hypoth*cos.

Comment: I have no idea how to proceed. It would be great if somebody provide a computational example.

Comment: If I can do it tomorrow.

Comment: Many thanks. You can also give SPSS example if you prefer.

Comment: @Andrej, is your question ("how to add projection points to the perpendicular line") about mathematics (how to compute the coordinates of the projection points) or about programming (how to do it in R using lda() function, how to plot it, etc.)?

Comment: @amoeba, about implementation (in R or any other programming language). But you can also discuss mathematics.

Comment: @amoeba, may you wish to comprise an answer? The OP would probably welcome a code in `R` which I can't offer being not its user.

Comment: @ttnphns: Unfortunately, I don't know R either... Will comment on the math later today, unless the issue is solved by then.

Comment: @ttnphns It's same to me: R, SPSS, Matlab. I just need some more concrete guidelines.

Comment: OK, Andrej, wait till evening. Maybe I will find time.

Comment: Andrej, so the discriminant axis (the onto which the points are projected on your Figure 1) is given by the first eigenvector of $W^{-1}B$. In case of only two classes this eigenvector is equal to $W^{-1}(m_1-m_2)$, where $m_i$ are class centroids. Normalize this vector (or the obtained eigenvector) to get the unit axis vector $v$. This is enough to draw the axis. To project the (centred) points onto this axis, you simply compute $Xvv^\top$. Here $vv^\top$ is a linear projector onto $v$. It looks like you are almost there, so maybe you can edit your post to explain where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: After your last comment It sees that I'm in the right way. But - just to be sure - I would also like to see other solutions. I will paste my solution as soon as possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The discriminant axis (the onto which the points are projected on your Figure 1) is given by the first eigenvector of $\mathbf{W}^{-1}\mathbf{B}$. In case of only two classes this eigenvector is proportional to $\mathbf{W}^{-1}(\mathbf{m}_1-\mathbf{m}_2)$, where $\mathbf{m}_i$ are class centroids. Normalize this vector (or the obtained eigenvector) to get the unit axis vector $\mathbf{v}$. This is enough to draw the axis.

To project the (centred) points onto this axis, you simply compute $\mathbf{X}\mathbf{v}\mathbf{v}^\top$. Here $\mathbf{v}\mathbf{v}^\top$ is a [linear projector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_%28linear_algebra%29#Orthogonal_projections) onto $\mathbf{v}$.

Here is the data sample from your dropbox and the LDA projection:

[image: LDA projection]

Here is MATLAB code to produce this figure (as requested):

```matlab
% # data taken from your example
X = [-0.9437    -0.0433; -2.4165    -0.5211; -2.0249    -1.0120; ...
    -3.7482 0.2826; -3.3314 0.1653; -3.1927 0.0043; -2.2233 -0.8607; ...
    -3.1965 0.7736; -2.5039 0.2960; -4.4509 -0.3555];
G = [1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2];

% # overall mean
mu = mean(X);

% # loop over groups
for g=1:max(G)
    mus(g,:) = mean(X(G==g,:)); % # class means
    Ng(g) = length(find(G==g)); % # number of points per group
end

Sw = zeros(size(X,2)); % # within-class scatter matrix
Sb = zeros(size(X,2)); % # between-class scatter matrix
for g=1:max(G)
    Xg = bsxfun(@minus, X(G==g,:), mus(g,:)); % # centred group data
    Sw = Sw + transpose(Xg)*Xg;
    Sb = Sb + Ng(g)*(transpose(mus(g,:) - mu)*(mus(g,:) - mu));
end

St = transpose(bsxfun(@minus,X,mu)) * bsxfun(@minus,X,mu); % # total scatter matrix
assert(sum(sum((St-Sw-Sb).^2)) < 1e-10, 'Error: Sw + Sb ~= St')

% # LDA
[U,S] = eig(Sw\Sb);

% # projecting data points onto the first discriminant axis
Xcentred = bsxfun(@minus, X, mu);
Xprojected = Xcentred * U(:,1)*transpose(U(:,1));
Xprojected = bsxfun(@plus, Xprojected, mu);

% # preparing the figure
colors = [1 0 0; 0 0 1];
figure
hold on
axis([-5 0 -2.5 2.5])
axis square

% # plot discriminant axis
plot(mu(1) + U(1,1)*[-2 2], mu(2) + U(2,1)*[-2 2], 'k')
% # plot projection lines for each data point
for i=1:size(X,1)
    plot([X(i,1) Xprojected(i,1)], [X(i,2) Xprojected(i,2)], 'k--')
end
% # plot projected points
scatter(Xprojected(:,1), Xprojected(:,2), [], colors(G, :))
% # plot original points
scatter(X(:,1), X(:,2), [], colors(G, :), 'filled')
```

Comment: Excellent!So helpful,one question:why are we interested in the 1st eigen vector alone ?

Answer (score 5):

And "my" solution. Many thanks to @ttnphns and @amoeba!

```
set.seed(2014)
library(MASS)
library(DiscriMiner) # For scatter matrices
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
# Generate multivariate data
mu1 <- c(2, -3)
mu2 <- c(2, 5)
rho <- 0.6
s1 <- 1
s2 <- 3
Sigma <- matrix(c(s1^2, rho * s1 * s2, rho * s1 * s2, s2^2), byrow = TRUE, nrow = 2)
n <- 50
# Multivariate normal sampling
X1 <- mvrnorm(n, mu = mu1, Sigma = Sigma)
X2 <- mvrnorm(n, mu = mu2, Sigma = Sigma)
X <- rbind(X1, X2)
# Center data
Z <- scale(X, scale = FALSE)
# Class variable
y <- rep(c(0, 1), each = n)

# Scatter matrices
B <- betweenCov(variables = X, group = y)
W <- withinCov(variables = X, group = y)

# Eigenvectors
ev <- eigen(solve(W) %*% B)$vectors
slope <- - ev[1,1] / ev[2,1]
intercept <- ev[2,1]

# Create projections on 1st discriminant
P <- Z %*% ev[,1] %*% t(ev[,1])

# ggplo2 requires data frame
my.df <- data.frame(Z1 = Z[, 1], Z2 = Z[, 2], P1 = P[, 1], P2 = P[, 2])

plt <- ggplot(data = my.df, aes(Z1, Z2))
plt <- plt + geom_segment(aes(xend = P1, yend = P2), size = 0.2, color = "gray")
plt <- plt + geom_point(aes(color = factor(y)))
plt <- plt + geom_point(aes(x = P1, y = P2, colour = factor(y)))
plt <- plt + scale_colour_brewer(palette = "Set1")
plt <- plt + geom_abline(intercept = intercept, slope = slope, size = 0.2)
plt <- plt + coord_fixed()
plt <- plt + xlab(expression(X[1])) + ylab(expression(X[2]))
plt <- plt + theme_bw()
plt <- plt + theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 8),
                   axis.text.x  = element_text(size = 8),
                   axis.title.y = element_text(size = 8),
                   axis.text.y  = element_text(size = 8),
                   legend.position = "none")
plt
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) Nice plot! Do you maybe want to remove at least some of the code excerpts from your question to improve readability? It's up to you, of course.

Comment: This code is not reproducible. Can you introduce variable `x`, `intercept` and `slope`?

Comment: Fixed; it works now.

Comment: hi,why are we not using the 2nd discriminant?